# JavaScript inserting css into .setAttribute()

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Colors</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Green</li>
        <li>Bleu</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        background-color: #8fbc8f;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

.first { color: red; }
.second { color: green; }
.third { color: blue; }
```

I need to use the .setAttribute() so that 'Red' gets the .first from CSS, 'Green' gets the .second and 'Blue' gets the .third. I've tried many things but i don't know which name and value I have to use so my code is correct.

Below is my script at the moment which doesn't seem to work. Can somebody tell me how I can do this?

```
function Colors() {
    let color = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    color[0].setAttribute("demo.css","first");
    color[1].setAttribute("demo.css","second");
    color[2].setAttribute("demo.css","third")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `class` attribute:

```
color[0].setAttribute("class", "first")
```

```js
function Colors() {
    let color = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    color[0].setAttribute("class", "first");
    color[1].setAttribute("class", "second");
    color[2].setAttribute("class", "third");
}
Colors()
```

```css
body {
        background-color: #8fbc8f;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

.first { color: red; }
.second { color: green; }
.third { color: blue; }
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Colors</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Green</li>
        <li>Blue</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: probably better at this point to use the `element.classList` interface to reconcile dynamic class names.